# Composition of interfaces in Go

Tags: oop, interface, go

Is there a way to make an interface also include the methods defined by another interface in Go?

For example:

```
type BasicDatabase interface {
    CreateTable(string) error
    DeleteTable(string) error
}

type SpecificDatabase interface {
    CreateUserRecord(User) error
}
```

I would like a way to specify that the `SpecificDatabase` interface contains the `BasicDatabase` interface. Similar to the way Go lets you do composition of structs.

This way my methods can take a type that implements `SpecificDatabase`, but still call `CreateTable()` on it.

Comment: Like [`io.ReadWriteCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadWriteCloser)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This can be done the same way as when composing structs.

```
type BasicDatabase interface {
    CreateTable(string) error
    DeleteTable(string) error
}

type SpecificDatabase interface {
    BasicDatabase
    CreateUserRecord(User) error
}
```